# Apply jquery validation on bootstrap drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

I have the following bootstrap drop-down menu:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-3 control-label">Pens</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="btn-group btn-input">
            <button id="pensList"  type="button"
                class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control"
                data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span data-bind="label">Nothing selected</span> 
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul id="elements" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li id="my_li_id_0"><a href="#">Nothing selected</a></li>
              <li id="my_li_id_1"><a href="#">Ballpoint Pens</a></li>
              <li id="my_li_id_2"><a href="#">Rollerball Pens</a></li>
              <li id="my_li_id_3"><a href="#">Fountain Pens</a></li>
              <li id="my_li_id_4"><a href="#">Custom pens</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this script for making it drop down:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li',
function(event) {
     var $target = $(event.currentTarget);

     $target.closest('.btn-group').find(
        '[data-bind="label"]').text( 
            $target.text()).end().children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');

        return false;
});
```

How can I apply **jquery** **validation** on it, raising error on the element with id **my_li_id_0**?

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin only validates standard data input elements... `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`; that does not include unordered lists, `<ul>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The jQuery Validate plugin can *only* validate `input`, `textarea`, and `select` elements contained within a `form` container.  It cannot validate an unordered list. ( *EDIT: In newer versions, it can also validate certain kinds of elements with a `contenteditable` attribute.* )

You'll have to construct a workaround.  Something like this...

1. Bind an event to the Bootstrap drop-down menu that's fired whenever the user makes or changes a selection.
2. Whenever that event from #1 is fired, copy the desired value from the list into a hidden `input` element.
3. Set the plugin's `ignore` option to `[]` so nothing is ignored and hidden `input` elements are validated.
4. Set your validation rules on the `name` of the hidden `input` element.
5. Use the `.valid()` method within your function on #2 above to trigger a validation test on the hidden `input` element whenever the selection is changed.
6. Use a conditional within the plugin's `errorPlacement` callback function to put the validation message in a location more relevant to the Bootstrap pulldown menu.  You'll need a conditional in order to preserve the default error placement code for the other elements.

---

BTW:  Your numerical `id`...

```
<li id="1">
```

...might be technically correct in HTML5, however, an `id` starting with a number could be a problem in other areas.  More info:  [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/79022#79022)

Comment: Saved me: Set the plugin's ignore option to [] so nothing is ignored and hidden input elements are validated.