# Jquery Combobox + validation of underlying dropdown + jquery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox, jquery-validate

I am developing an application in asp.net mvc and trying to do validation using jquery validation plugin.

I have a dropdownlist which is being converted to combobox using jQuery code here:

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

The problem I am having is regarding validation. If a user submits the form without choosing a value from the dropdown list then a error message is shown on the post back.

The problem I am having is that the error message goes away if I manually select a value from the underlying dropdown. However, if I use the combobox then the error message doesn't go away even though the value in the underlying dropdown changes.

The code in the combobox which updates the value is:

```
this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
```

How is the validation in jquery done? Does it not check if the value of the underlying dropdown changes?

Thanks!

---- HTML Markup and jQuery.

For HTML. I am using asp .net mvc code as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property.Area, new { @class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" })
  <div class="input-group col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Property.Area, Model.AreaLookUps, "--Select Area--", new { onchange = "initializeMapAndGeocode();", @class = "form-control combobox" })</div> 
  <div id="property-area-error" class="col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-2"><span class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property.Area)</span></div>
</div>
```

This generates the following markup

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="Property_Area">Area*</label>
  <div class="input-group col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control combobox" data-error-div-id="property-area-error" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Area* must be a number." data-val-required="Please select the appropiate option." id="Property_Area" name="Property.Area" onchange="initializeMapAndGeocode();">
    <option value="">--Select Area--</option>
```

I don't have any validation method. I have simply included the jQuery validate and jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation libraries.

Thanks.

-- Update
I have created a workaround by adding giving the error div an "id" and adding the id as a data-attribute to the "select". In the combobox script, I hide this error div when combobox value changes. This might not be the the best solution though - but its a workaround.

Comment: Please show your `.validate()` method as well as the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> *"How is the validation in jquery done? Does it not check if the value of the underlying dropdown changes?"*

It simply checks the *specified* `input`, `textarea`, and `select` elements (within a `form` container).  If you're doing something that moves data from a GUI element into a hidden `input`, `textarea`, or `select` element, it's up to you to manually declare your rules on the correct element.  You'll probably also need to manually trigger validation on the element using the `.valid()` method.

Something very similar is done here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976174/594235